# Burndown chart for TFS with Ideal trend starting at max(remaining hours) and not first date(remaining hours)

Tags: tfs, agile, burndowncharts

We use the MSF Agile 5.0 process template in TFS. I wonder if anyone has tweaked the Burndown chart so the Ideal trend would get it's height from the highest point the Remaining work has reached and not the value remaining work has at day 1 of the iteration.

In the burndown below the Ideal Trend would start at 130 hours and not 20.

[image: lot of work added later]][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lijcb.png)

Does anyone have an rdl-file to share?

Here is a question that shows the code in the report but I don't know how to change it (http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sv-SE/tfsreporting/thread/e901242b-3a82-41e6-8fa4-d0ab29bceb5e)

Answer (score 1):

I wonder if you can just simply set the start date of the iteration to Nov 6th for example?

Comment: Yes, that's a possibility, but I don't want to tweak the report based on the data. I want to change how the chart works to the way. e.g. Urban Turtle renders them (http://i40.tinypic.com/ne6ntu.png)

Comment: You can modify reports using Business Intelligence Development Studio.  See this: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg309379.aspx

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, Rami. I have Report Builder installed and I have used it to do some minor modifications to some reports. The above task, however, is more complicated than the kind of modifications I have the knowledge and the time to do.

Comment: Heh, changing the sprint start date is (a) very sneaky and (2) works like a charm! Thanks!